# Print even numbers from 1-100 with 5 numbers per line

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, iteration

trying to brush up on some basic javascript and I'm wondering how you would solve this. I found a way but it's pretty ugly and I'd appreciate some more experienced eyes letting me know what they thing. Basically, just iterate over the numbers 1-100 and print all even numbers in groups of five on each line. So line one would be 2,4,5,8,10, line 2 is 12,14,16,18,20. Here is what I have so far:

```
var counter = 0;
var line=[];


for(var i = 0; i<=100; i++){
  if(i%2==0){
    if(line.length <5){
    line[counter] = i;
    counter++
    }else{
      console.log(line);
      line=[];
      counter=0;
      line[counter] =i;
    }
  }
  }
console.log(line);
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems that I see with the code is that you are looping from 0 instead of 1, and that you are not increasing the counter in the `else` block.

Fixing that you get:

```
var counter = 0;
var line=[];

for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0){
    if (line.length < 5) {
      line[counter] = i;
      counter++
    } else {
      console.log(line);
      line=[];
      counter = 0;
      line[counter] = i;
      counter++
    }
  }
}
console.log(line);
```

Instead of looping from 1 to 100 and checking if the number is even, just loop from 2 to 100 in steps of two. You don't need the counter at all, you can push the items into the array. Instead of repeating the code that adds an item to the array in the `if` and `else` blocks you can just do it once after.

With those simplifications you get:

```
var line=[];

for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i += 2) {
  if (line.length == 5) {
    console.log(line);
    line=[];
  }
  line.push(i);
}
console.log(line);
```

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful. I'm glad to you know you still have to spit out the final console.log statement as the final loop through for 100 will get the length to 5, but post the check and it won't iterate through agin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
console.log(2,4,6,8,10);
console.log(12,14,16,18,20);
console.log(22,24,26,28,30);
console.log(32,34,36,38,40);
console.log(42,44,46,48,50);
console.log(52,54,56,58,60);
console.log(62,64,66,68,70);
console.log(72,74,76,78,80);
console.log(82,84,86,88,90);
console.log(92,94,96,98,100);
```

With most hypothetical programming problems, it's most worthwhile to address their lack of rooting in reality and do what is simplest — reality is sure to prove to be much more complicated.

As for learning exercises, those typically work best when you solve them yourself.

Comment: In other words, this smells of homework. While this answer is almost positively not what the OP wanted, it is indeed what they asked for. ++

Comment: It's not homework. I'm trying to prep for an interview and need to get comfortable with simple javascript loops. It's just practice. Also, it's not like I'm not trying here I'm just looking for an extra set of eyes to refactor is all.

Answer (score 1):

```
var line = [];
//you are uninterested in odd numbers, so increment the counter by 2
for(var i = 0; i <= 1000; i = i + 2) {
    line.push(i);
    if((i + 2) % 5 === 0) { //every 5 lines print result
        console.log(line);
        line = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>
  var counter = 0;
  var line = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= 100; i += 2) {
    line[counter] = i;
    counter++;
    if (line.length == 5) {
      console.log(line);
      counter = 0;
      line = [];
    }
  }
</script>
```

Same as yours, but use a loop incrementing by 2